# csv not populating in s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i have a function set up that will convert my df into a csv and pushes it to s3 (it does not save locally i am wanting it to save to the s3 bucket)

```
def to_csv_s3(name, addy, zip_code):

zip_array = []
for x in range(len(name)):
    zip_array.append(zip_code)
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['zip_code'] = zip_array
df['name'] = name
df['address'] = addy 
print(df)
bucket = 'jcalkins-source'
file_name = f'{zip_code}.csv'
s3_client = boto3.client(
    "s3",
    aws_access_key_id = access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key = secret_access_key
)
with io.StringIO() as buffer:
    df.to_csv(buffer, index=False)
    response = s3_client.put_object(
        Bucket=bucket, Key='jcalkins_source/csv/{zip_code}.csv', Body = buffer.getvalue()
    )
status = response.get("ResponseMetadata", {}).get("HTTPStatusCode")

if status == 200:
    print(f"Successful S3 put_object response. Status - {status}")
else:
    print(f"Unsuccessful S3 put_object response. Status - {status}")
```

after the function runs i set it up to tell me the response status. Whenever i run it i get status 200 but theres no file in my bucket.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out. where you set key equal to a file path if you just want it to go straight into the bucket and not go into any folders you only need to put

```
Key='file_name.csv'
```

if you are wanting a specific folder you can specify that before the file